# AVAudioSession setCategory error

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudiosession

Trying this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error setting category: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Getting the error back "Error setting category: UIView" but am not sure how to go about fixing this. Not entirely sure what it's telling me.

Help please!

**EDIT**

Audio Playback:

```
NSURL *audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DemoSong" withExtension:@"m4a"];
NSError *error;

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

[_audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[_audioPlayer setMeteringEnabled:YES];
[_visualizer setAudioPlayer:_audioPlayer];

[_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_audioPlayer play];
NSLog(@"play audio");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the return value of `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]`, as it returns `YES` if it succeeded and `NO` if it failed.

Only look at the `error` variable if the return value of `setCategory:error:` is `NO`.

Comment: Checking the return value gives me a true. Audio still not playing though.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code used for the actual audio playback?

Comment: @Lagoo87 Try to check if `_audioPlayer == nil` after you do `self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];`.

Comment: Yea- it says it's null for some reason.

Comment: Ah I got it- the file wasn't Copied into the Bundled Resources. Thank you helping me track this down :)

Comment: That's because `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` returns nil if it fails to initialize the AVAudioPlayer object. I reckon the problem is with the audio file path. Try logging it and make sure it is correct.

Comment: NB: Apple recommend `setCategory:mode:options:error:` over `setCategory:withOptions:error:` so that category & mode are set simultaneously. See the discussion notes on this page: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
NSError * error = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
if(NO == success)
{
    NSLog(@"Error setting category: %@", [error localizedDescription])
}
```

and see if you get something more descriptive and helpful.